# Is there a bijective function where $f: \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q \setminus \{0\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, relations

$f(x) = {1\over x}$ should be wrong, as the function isn't defined for $0$. Another could be: $f(x) = 2^x$, but is there anything else except functions of this type?
I was thinking of something with the injectivity to be provable by simply doing $f(x)=f(x')$, as I'm pretty much limited to doing it this way.
In case there's no such, how could I start on finding such a function?

Comment: You need to think differently about what a function is. In the end attempts to build such a function out of "natural" functions which are continuous on the real line is going to cause problems because $\mathbb R$ is connected and $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ is not.

Comment: Try one formula for $f(x)$ when $x$ is a non-negative integer, and another formula for the rest of them.

Comment: The function $x \mapsto 2^x$ is not acceptable. Notice that $\tfrac{1}{2}$ *is* a rational number while $2^{1/2} = \sqrt{2}$ *is not* a rational number.

Comment: @user73691 : both sets are countably infinite, so the answer is "yes".  Do you need to actually find $f$?  That is a different question.

Comment: can you find one which is order preserving?

Comment: @user27182: Yes. See my answer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila. that was for OP, but cool.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: $\mathbb Q$ is countable.

Comment: I was going to give an answer, but this such an excellent hint and the problem deserves some work, because this will help to build some intuition about these situations.

Comment: countably *infinite*; the word *infinite* is also key here :)

Comment: @GitGud. I don't think that it is. If one was to forget this then they would be unable to "pair off" the rationals in the sequencial way that solves this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Define a function $\varphi:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$ as follows. If $x$ is is a rational number which is **not** one of the numbers $0,1,2,3,\dots$, let $\varphi(x)=x$. It is left to you to decide on $\varphi(x)$ for the numbers where it has not yet been defined.

**Remark:** You may want to check into Hilbert's infinite hotel.

Comment: Love the remark in this btw

Answer (score 4):

Recall that $\Bbb Q$ is countable therefore there is such a bijection. But there is actually more than just a bijection.

There is an order preserving bijection, that is, there is a bijection $f$ such that $f(x)<f(y)\iff x<y$. The reason is that every countable dense linear order without endpoints is isomorphic to the rational numbers. It is easy to check that $\Bbb Q\setminus\{0\}$ is such order (with the usual order restricted to exclude $0$, of course).

The proof is not very hard, but slightly technical, you can find the reasoning [here, on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method).

Answer (score 1):

Use Robert's hint. Since both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$ are both countably infinite, we may write
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{Q} &=\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\} \\
\mathbb{Q\setminus\{0\}} &= \{b_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}
\end{align}
$$
where $i\neq j$ implies $a_i\neq a_j$ and $b_i\neq b_j$.
Now, the map $f:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$ given by $f(a_n)=b_n$ is invertible.